# MySql view with one column being an array from a table column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a mysql view that pulls multiple values from one table into just one column in the view.  I'm trying a different approach for the alias table used by postfix so that I can manage the additions and removals better for any given alias

Table

```
john@u.com         alias1@u.com
joy@u.com          alias1@u.com
jack@u.com         alias2@u.com
```

View

```
alias1@u.com       john@u.com,joy@u.com
alias2@u.com       jack@u.com
```

What would the mysql view code be to create this view?  Thanks for your time and responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT email1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email2) email2
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY email1
```

**Result**

```
|       EMAIL1 |               EMAIL2 |
---------------------------------------
| alias1@u.com | john@u.com,joy@u.com |
| alias2@u.com |           jack@u.com |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e7e9/1)

Comment: Gah, I knew it was something stupid simple.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat while defining the view

```
select column2, group_concat(column1)
from table1
group by column2
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

Create Table:

```
create table email (
  id serial,
  address varchar(254),
  alias varchar(254)
);
```

Select Statement:

```
select group_concat(address) as addresses, alias
from email
group by alias;
```

Create View:

```
create view aliases as
select group_concat(address) as addresses, alias
from email group by alias;
```